# Google asset links not working in android

Tags: digital-assets-links

I want to use *google digital asset links* feature for the purpose of opening a designated host link to open in a designated app on mobile devices, if the app is installed.

I have done all the settings,
1. uploaded assetlinks.json with package-name and sha256 key to the .well-known folder on root of host.
2. added meta tag in the manifest with android:name="asset_statements".

Even after successful verification i am not able to open a link from message inbox to my app directly.